# Найти строку в файле и вывести на экран

Tags: c++, visual-c++

С++

В файле записаны строка "string", и еще 2 строки ниже.
Я знаю номер этой строки "num".

Задача: вывести на экран и удалить из файла 
строку с номером num, строку num+1 и строку num+2.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
  ++counter;

 if (counter == num) {
  // работа со строкой line
 }
 // для num+1 и num+2 аналогичные проверки
}
```